# When will Gazebo be catkin-ized in ROS?

Tags: gazebo, cmake, catkin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In ROS Groovy, the Gazebo debian is still currently using rosbuild, and the Gazebo installation instructions say that ROS users should not install from source. Additionally, Gazebo for ROS is still on version 1.2 instead of 1.3. The reason I need Gazebo to be catkinized is because I tried following your [animate joint](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/intermediate/animate_joint) tutorial and CMake can't find Gazebo. I assume that is because Gazebo on my computer is installed here:

> /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/share/gazebo-1.2/

I tried sourcing the setup.sh in the above folder but it didn't help CMake. I also tried catkinizing the animate joint tutorial but realized it wouldn't work because Gazebo is still a dry package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/594/when-will-gazebo-be-catkin-ized-in-ros?/) by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 369 on 2013-01-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo is a standalone package. ROS will eventually use our binary installation. So, Gazebo won't be catkin-ized because it's not a ROS package or stack.

The proper way to use Gazebo is to install the standalone version of Gazebo, and use pkg-config to find it.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-01-14**:
This seems to run counter to what this website says: "ROS Users: Never install Gazebo from here. Use these instructions." On this page: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.2/install

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on 2013-01-14**:
dave, this changed with version 1.3. The installation instructions for that version state what nate posted. I found that quite confusing, so I've asked for recommendations for ros users here: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/782/recommended-way-of-using-gazebo-with-ros-groovy/

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-01-14**:
Gazebo 1.3 install instructions are correct.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

at some point, [simulator_gazebo stack](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo) will no longer contain a gazebo binary within it, instead, it will depend on gazebo as a system dependency.  simulator_gazebo stack will contain just the plugins and tools for interfacing ROS with gazebo.

In latest groovy trunk, gazebo binary in simulator_gazebo has caught up-to-date with [gazebo version 1.3](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.3/install), but with a minor difference, it still depends on `parser_deprecated.cc` library.  The very last hurdle to cross before switching to system installed gazebo is to tic-toc out of the dependency on [pre-gazebo-1.0 XML](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/82/add-support-for-pre-gazebo-10x-model-xml), requiring any existing urdf with old gazebo XML format to be converted to SDF 1.3+.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-01-10**:
I have created a SDF version of my robot (this was very time-consuming) and so am ready for the switch. However, I am very curious: is there a discussion about getting rid of URDF all together in the ROS community? SDF does seem much more powerful (yay parallel linkages) but now I have 2 files